# Reference Particular Namespace that appears in two referenced Assemblies

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I'm trying to use the Newtonsoft.Json.Schema nuget package. It has a dependency to Newtonsoft.Json nuget package.

The issue is that both packages contain a namespace called "Newtonsoft.Json.Schema." I want to use the one that does not appear in the Newtonsoft.Json package. However when I write

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema
```

It always uses the namespace contained in the Newtonsoft.Json package.

Any ideas?

Comment: Namespaces and assemblies are *orthogonal*. When you have a `using` directive, it is saying "make types in this namespace visibile, no matter what assembly those types are in". Namespaces and assemblies are *not* linked together.

Comment: I.e. you probably don't think twice about `using System;` at the top of a file, despite the fact that you may be using e.g. `System.Int32` (from mscorlib) and `System.Uri` (from System).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So how do you suggest solving this issue or your saying it isn't possible? How does it know which namespace to choose?

Comment: I'm saying it's *not* an issue at all. It's *normal* for multiple assemblies to contribute types to a *single* namespace, and when you say `using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema`, you should be seeing all types within that namespace for *all* assemblies that you're referencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my issue had to do with reading the old documentation. In the packages mentioned they renamed the classes so it wasn't an issue.

In the [old version](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JTokenIsValid.htm) the json schema class is called: `JsonSchema` while in the [new](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/JTokenIsValid.htm) it is called `JSchema`. So that fixed everything.

In terms of my question above the proper way to fix this issue would be to use **[extern alias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx)**. Here is a great [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx) that explains.

I hope that helps someone.